# SAS ODS RTF Table column header

Tags: sas, rtf, ods

I am creating a RTF file using SAS ODS. When I add a text using "ODS TEXT", the column headers of a table are not repeating in next page but comes only at the start of the table.
When I remove the "ODS TEXT", I get columns names in all pages. Since I need a text above the table (not in header/title), can you suggest a solution?

```
data chk;
 set sashelp.class;
 output; output;
run;

ods rtf file = "xx\check.rtf";
ods escapechar = '^';

title " ";

ods text="ods text";

proc report nowd data=chk ;
run;

ods rtf close;
```

Comment: What version of SAS are you using? Should be something like SAS 9.4TSM6.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. It is SAS 9.4 (TS1M6)